# Как сделать так, чтобы в кластерере при нажатии на кластер балун появлялся, а при нажатии на отдельный маркер - нет?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на маркер открывалась моя форма, а при нажатии на кластер - обычный балун кластера. Но при нажатии на маркер открывается как своя форма, так и балун маркера.

Никак не могу сделать, чтобы кластер маркера не открывался.

Пробовал разные варианты типа:

```
e.getSourceEvent().originalEvent.domEvent.preventDefault();
e.getSourceEvent().originalEvent.domEvent.stopPropagation();
e.getSourceEvent().originalEvent.domEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.getSourceEvent().originalEvent.domEvent.originalEvent.preventDefault();
e.getSourceEvent().originalEvent.domEvent.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
```

не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Всё оказалось просто. В objectManager необходимо правильно выставлять опции `geoObjectOpenBalloonOnClick` и `clusterOpenBalloonOnClick`.